# Publishing my first android application in Android market

Tags: android, publish, google-play

I want publish my app in the android market. How much time does it take to make an android developer account verified by google. also what other things I should do ?

Comment: According to few months ago, unlike, windows mobile developer, the google account is immediate (well, as soon as you pay the fee).
I can only suggest you to use a propriety gmail account for that purpose and not use your personal account. Good luck

Comment: Well it didn't helped me since it took much more than 10days . still I'll mark it as Accepted if that makes you happy :-)

Comment: Thanks. Which part took 10 days? I can update my answer or you can post your own answer with your experiences. I'm sorry the original answer didn't help you, but now the important thing is that other users get a good, correct answer.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Google has an extensive guide on the steps to take an the things you need to publish your application on the market:

Preparing to publish: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/preparing.html

Publishing on Android market: http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/publishing.html

After paying for the developer account, it takes less than a day to get approved.

In my experience, when you have prepared everything, the time it takes to upload apk and images, and paste the description text is 10 minutes.

After pressing 'Publish' it takes around 15 minutes for the app to appear on the market.

Comment: For newbies: now it can take 30 minutes or a couple of hours. I don't know if it is location or time dependent.

Comment: What are the other things that I should do after publishing an app? I just found out that I have to link my app in admob.

Comment: @Mr.Nacho, it would be more effective to ask that in a question than in a comment.

Comment: @Marmoy But people might say that it is not a programming question.